# Having issue on Adding Smooth Continuous Animation to Set of SVG Circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

Using `Animate.css` I am trying to add some `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect to the  svg `circles` continuously in a way that every time 10 circle should be in the page but as you can see there always white gap between the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`!

Can you please help me to figure out how to fix this and add smooth animation for all circles (10 at each time) to randomly display and fade out in the svg? in Pure JS or CSS way or even using this  `Animate.css` library

```js
  var numbers = [];
setInterval(() => {
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let a = true,
      n;
  while(a) {
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    a = numbers.includes(n);
  }
  numbers.push(n);
}
  
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
$('circle').eq( numbers[i]).removeClass('animate__fadeOut').addClass('animate__fadeIn');
       index = i;
}
  var clear = function(){
        $('circle').removeClass('animate__fadeIn').addClass('animate__fadeOut');
  }
  setTimeout(clear, 2500);
  numbers = [];
  
  }, 4000);
```

```html
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="576px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 576 200" enable-background="new 0 0 576 200" xml:space="preserve">
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="481.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="421.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="361.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="161.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="301.5" cy="164.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="271.5" cy="164.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="241.5" cy="159.907" r="2.088"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="211.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="121.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="91.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="159.907" r="5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="159.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="421.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="141.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="301.5" cy="144.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="271.5" cy="144.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="241.5" cy="139.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="211.5" cy="139.907" r="7.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="139.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="91.5" cy="139.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="139.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="139.907" r="6.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="481.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="421.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="361.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="121.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="271.5" cy="124.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="241.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="211.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="121.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="91.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="119.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="84.907" r="2.198"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="481.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="421.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="361.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="84.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="241.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="211.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="82.907" r="7"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="121.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="91.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="82.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="479.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="64.907" r="9.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="423.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="361.5" cy="64.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="301.5" cy="62.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="239.5" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="62.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="62.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="121.5" cy="62.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="62.907" r="2.305"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="62.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="541.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="511.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="481.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="451.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="421.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="391.5" cy="44.907" r="3.076"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="361.5" cy="44.907" r="7"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="301.5" cy="44.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="241.5" cy="42.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="211.5" cy="42.907" r="7"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="181.5" cy="42.907" r="2.36"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="151.5" cy="42.907" r="5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="121.5" cy="42.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="91.5" cy="42.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="61.5" cy="42.907" r="7"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="31.5" cy="42.907" r="5.25"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="496.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="466.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="436.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="376.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="316.834" cy="161.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="286.834" cy="164.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="256.833" cy="164.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="226.833" cy="159.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="159.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="159.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="159.907" r="3.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="106.833" cy="159.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="159.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="159.907" r="3.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="466.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="436.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="316.834" cy="141.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="256.833" cy="144.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="226.833" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="139.907" r="5.529"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="139.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="496.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="466.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="436.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="376.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="316.834" cy="121.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="226.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="106.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="119.907" r="3.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="119.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="271.5" cy="40.407" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="496.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="466.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="436.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="376.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="291.334" cy="84.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="226.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="106.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="82.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="64.907" r="3.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="496.834" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="64.907" r="3.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="376.834" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="316.834" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="286.834" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="256.833" cy="64.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="62.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="526.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="496.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="466.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="436.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="406.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="376.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="346.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="316.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="286.834" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="256.833" cy="44.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="226.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="196.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="166.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="136.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="106.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="76.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="46.833" cy="42.907" r="4.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="111.333" cy="140.408" r="9.5"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="96.75" cy="62.907" r="11.068"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="366.75" cy="141.907" r="11.068"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="216.75" cy="62.907" r="6.575"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="489.408" cy="141.907" r="9.908"/>
    <circle class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut" cx="331.5" cy="64.907" r="7"/>
    </svg>
```